# Do you enable query_cache for Magento?

Tags: database, query

All tutorials for **optimizing Magento performance** I read suggest that we should enable query cache in `mysql -> my.cnf`

However, I read a lot of other articles and even the mysqltuner script also suggest that this should be disabled if you use innodb

So what is the correct solution?

> http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory#query_cache
>   https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63415/how-to-decide-whether-to-enable-mysql-query-cache-using-innodb

vs

> https://www.crucialhosting.com/knowledgebase/improving-magento-performance-mysql-query-cache

Comment: Please post the entire TEXT results of your MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report for consideration. With it, we will know how many tables are MyISAM and Innodb and the space they occupy and many other details, such as RAM installed, ENGINES available to eliminate GUESSING at your instance environment.

Comment: Repeated request, Please post the entire TEXT results of your MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report for consideration. With it, we will know how many tables are MyISAM and Innodb and the space they occupy and many other details, such as RAM installed, ENGINES available to eliminate GUESSING at your instance environment.

Answer (score 0):

As query_cache should be enabled or not it depends on the DB Engine which is used by your server.

If your server is using huge amount of tables with Inno DB engine then query_cache implementation will 
increase the overhead.

But if your server is using MyISAM engine for many tables then query_cache enabling will 
benifit you. 
For knowing the reason that why innodb doesn't support query_cache you may follow this link-

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23699/is-the-overhead-of-frequent-query-cache-invalidation-ever-worth-it/23727#23727

Here is how you can enble the query_cache  from my.cnf file-

```
query_cache_size = 268435456
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 1048576
```

Here is how you can disable the query_cache from same file-

```
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_limit = 0
```

And then restart mysql.

Comment: Please post the entire TEXT results of your MySQLTuner.pl (perl) report for consideration. With it, we will know how many tables are MyISAM and Innodb and the space they occupy and many other details, such as RAM installed, ENGINES available to eliminate GUESSING at your instance environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if my Magento 2.3 install uses alot of tables. I ran mysqltuner, and it said to set query_cache_size = 0

should I just listen?
Any harm in doing so?